# Any way to avoid the black background while video loads on Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I am trying to build a Kindle Fire app that will replace a static image with a video in response to a user action.  The problem is that everything is on a white background, and the video player loads with a black background.  So, to the user, it looks like an image on a white background, followed by an instant of a big black rectangle, followed by the playing video.

Is there any way to avoid that black background?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the video in a background thread, then do whatever you want to the background in the main thread?